# How can I Change startup data in asp.net core in runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity

I have some code for Identity setting in startup project like:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Password settings
    options.Password.RequiredDigit = SystemSetting.RequiredDigit;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = SystemSetting.RequireLength;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = SystemSetting.RNA;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = SystemSetting.RequireUppercase;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = SystemSetting.RequireLowercase;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = SystemSetting.RequireUniqueChars;

    // Lockout settings
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = SystemSetting.MaxFaildAccessAttempts;
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = SystemSetting.AllowedForNewUsers;

    // User settings
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = SystemSetting.RequireUniqueEmail;
});
```

And SystemSetting Class has this static property:

```
public class SystemSetting
{
    public static bool RequireDigit {get; set;};
    public static bool RequireLength {get; set;};
    public static bool RNA {get; set;};
    public static bool RequireUppercase {get; set;};
    public static bool RequireLowercase {get; set;};
    public static bool RequireUniqueChars {get; set;};
    public static bool MaxFaildAccessAttempts {get; set;};
    public static bool AllowedForNewUsers {get; set;};
    public static bool RequireUniqueEmail {get; set;};
}
```

And this property set in everywhere in the project;

With this code, you can pass dynamic data in Identity options. and I generate a System Setting that if the ApplicationManager wants to change this default data, he can.

Now! as you know, when the application starts, the startup run just one time forever.
How can I change this data??[in RunTime] or how can I pass data to startup??[in RunTime]

Comment: Long story short - how can you re-read changed configuration data? The configuration middleware already supports that. Which means, instead of using that static class create an object that you can load from configuration and can be updated automatically when the configuration (eg settings ) changes. *Don't* use a static class, inject the settings as an `IOptions<MyConfigObject> wherever they are needed so whoever reads them gets the latest value

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Do you mean that if I inject IOptions<MyConfigObject> and set the dynamic data in Option instead SystemSetting(static class), after that everything will be change??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, startup methods are only ran once, but if you really want to do it in startup you can make a service that provides an Options object with updated values and register the service within the ConfigureServices method and use that wherever you need the options. The service will then be available in the app and in the configure method, and is resolved with dependancy injection. Or alternatively you can use an injection framework to achieve the same (e.g. Ninject, Autofac etc..).

The ConfigureServices [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.1#the-configureservices-method)

Comment: What is the actual solution? This answer just points to generic documentation. Do you have any example mock code? thank you